# Bootstrap Masonry with overlapping cards

Tags: masonry

i am using this bootstrap masonry template: [bootstrap masonry](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/masonry/)
and it is working fine but overlapps the cards on first load if i use the attribute "data-masonry" in my row.

```
<div class="row" data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true, "itemSelector": ".col-sm-6" }'>
```

i figured out that i have to use the [imagesloaded](https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded) function. for get this working i need to call the masonry from vanilla js instead the "data-masonry" attribut. But this is not working at all.

if i delete the attribute and add the js code the masonry is not working anymore.

```
      <script>
    var msnry = new Masonry('.row', {
      itemSelector: '.col-sm-6',
      percentPosition: true
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="container py-5">
    <div class="row">
```

i appreciate any help. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I created a gallery plugin, which collect images from server.
This plugin use jQuery 3.6.1, and bootstrap 5.2 (after v5 masonry is deprecated in BS)

The plugin create "coverimage" divs from the cover flagged images, and push these divs into a grid, and create "masonry" layout.
At first I can't find the solution for overlapping, main reason of the problem was the timing of "masonry" function call.
You have to call the "masonry" function after the images loaded and displayed.

> $("img").load( function(){ $("#mason_grid").masonry({ itemSelector: ".cover_wrapper"}) });

"#mason_grid" is the parent div of gallery,
".cover_wrapper" is a div with an image.

For more info:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/masonry/